# Get the latest month field value and sum of all months field value from a table with single query

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table similar as below. I need to get the latest month Score and total Salary for the member with one query in a single row as: M1 1800 32

| Month | MemberID | Salary | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-07 | M1 | 100 | 32 |
| 2023-06 | M1 | 200 | 22 |
| 2023-05 | M1 | 300 | 12 |
| 2023-04 | M1 | 300 | 33 |
| 2023-03 | M1 | 300 | 45 |
| 2023-02 | M1 | 300 | 72 |
| 2023-01 | M1 | 300 | 10 |

Please suggest a optimized and simple query.

I have achieved this but with window function, case statement and lots of max as there are more columns in my table.

```
SELECT MEMBER_ID,SUM(SALARY) AS SALARY,SUM(SCORE) AS SCORE
FROM(
SELECT MEMBER_ID,SALARY,
  , CASE WHEN RANK=1 THEN SCORE ELSE 0 END AS SCORE
FROM (
SELECT A.*, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY MEMBER_ID ORDER BY MONTH DESC) AS RANK 
FROM table A
  AND MONTH BETWEEN '2023-01' and '2023-08'                          
) A )GROUP BY 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please suggest a optimized and simple query.

You can use window function to get the latest month Score and total Salary for the member in a single row:

```
SELECT
  MEMBER_ID,
  SUM(SALARY) AS SALARY,
  LAST_VALUE(SCORE) OVER (PARTITION BY MEMBER_ID ORDER BY MONTH DESC) AS SCORE
FROM table
GROUP BY MEMBER_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as (
select 
    MemberID,
    Month,
    sum(salary) over(partition by MemberID) as Salary ,
    Score,
    ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by MemberId order by Month desc) as RNUM 
from table_name
)


select 
    MemberID,
    Salary,
    Score
from cte
```